# Don't shrink imageview or background when softkeyboard is open

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

When keyboard is open the background is shrinked. have a look on Quote:

[image]

Activity have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

And there is my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: Removing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` would help maybe?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท If I remove this line the button `next` became hidden under the keyboard

Comment: Try removing `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from the ImageView, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your Activity `Manifest` declare the activity view to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Then follow this code:

```
Bitmap bmImg; // Load a bitmap into bmImg 
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg); 
background.setGravity(Gravity.TOP); 
this.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```